# Is there a keyboard that can be held in your hands and not having to place it on a desk?

Tags: keyboards

I had a shoulder injury where I had to raise my arms about my head for 1 hr a day for rehab. And I found that a keyboard like this really helped me still able to work and not get behind, by just holding the keyboard lightly in my hands:

- [Anker Compact Wireless Keyboard for Tablets and Smartphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BVBHT1T5)

[image]

Is there a better alternative? Where ideally I'd be able to lift my hands and just type without worrying about it accidentally falling down?